# RecursiveDo in Idris? (Using value before it is defined while in do notation)

Tags: idris

Does Idris 2 have anything similar to Haskell's `RecursiveDo`. I have certain values that I would like to use before they are defined while in the `IO` monad. I am trying to build a cyclical FRP network. They implement the following interface:

```hs
interface Loop (a : Type) where
    loop : (a -> IO (b, a)) -> IO b
```

However using `loop` is ugly. Is there a better way?